# How to solve fatal error: 'eosiolib/types.hpp' file not found #include <eosiolib/types.hpp>?

Tags: eosiocpp, eosio.cdt, c++

After installing `eosio.cdt` 1.4.1, I am receiving this error from the compilation of my code where is included the header file `eosiolib/types.hpp`:

> fatal error: 'eosiolib/types.hpp' file not found
>
> `#include <eosiolib/types.hpp>`

Using the old compiler `eosiocpp` everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `eosiocpp` everything works fine because `types.hpp` is defined in the directory `...\eos\contracts\eosiolib`. In `eosio.cdt` in `...\eosio.cdt\libraries\eosiolib` there is only `types.h` and not `types.hpp` and so `types.hpp` cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, some breaking changes have been introduced and `types.hpp` is no more present in `eosio.cdt`. That of course is the reason of the error.

However, even if, in the docs https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt, clearly is specified under ***eosiolib C++ API*** that `eosiolib/types.hpp` has been removed, this section can be useful for the last updates:

***eosiolib/types.hpp***

```
Moved the typedef eosio::extensions_types to eosiolib/transaction.hpp.
Removed comparison functions for checksum structs.
Removal of eosio::char_to_symbol, eosio::string_to_name, eosio::name_suffix functions
Removal of the N macro. The ""_n operator or the name constructor should be used as a type safe replacement. Example: N(foo) -> "foo"_n, or N(foo) -> name("foo").
Moved eosio::name struct definition and ""_n operator to eosiolib/name.hpp
```